# Concatenation of strings and to check if the given string can be formed

Tags: algorithm, string-concatenation

Given a bigger string, a positive integer m and m smaller strings, check if the bigger string can
be formed by concatenation from the m smaller strings, using each string 0 or more times in
any order.

I know how to concatenate strings in C++.
But I'm finding it hard to find an algorithm for this problem.
Maybe overloaded operators, subsequence check etc will be needed and I can form the code. But I'm not able to find the algorithm. Please help!

Comment: Brute force approach would be to calculate the variations with repetitions (V[m, m]) of your smaller strings and check if any of those is equal to your bigger string. The problem with this algorithm is that it's complexity is O(m^m).

Comment: Another, better approach would be to see if any of the smaller strings is a substring of the big string starting at index 0. Once you find the match, you do the same again starting from index 0+length(smallstring). If many smaller strings match - then you have many problem branches to explore. If none - FAIL.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this. We keep removing all occurrences of the candidate substrings until finally either the result is empty or it is not. If it is empty then success otherwise it was not possible.

Bambo-Otrit has pointed out a flaw in this code below so doesn't quite meet the spec. Let's see what we can do about that, feel free to jump in anyone.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


using string = std::string;
using size_type= std::string::size_type;
using svector = std::vector<string>;

void eraseAllOccurences(const string& s, string& result){   

    string::size_type pos = string::npos;

    while ( (pos  = result.find(s) ) !=  string::npos){
        result.erase(pos, s.length());
    }    
}



int main(int, char**){

    const string targetString = "bcaaac";   
    const svector candidates = { "a", "b", "c" };

    string result = targetString;

    for(auto s : candidates)
        eraseAllOccurences(s, result);  

    std::cout << (result.empty() ? "success" : "failure") << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

==============================================================

OK. How about this for an attempt. Code needs tidying up a bit
and a whole heap of testing but will give you an idea of what am after.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <string_view>

using std::cout;
using std::string;
using size_type = std::string::size_type;
using svector = std::vector<string>;        //string vector
using ivector = std::vector<std::size_t>;   //index vector
using sview = std::string_view;
using sviews = std::vector<sview>;

inline bool isSubStringOf(sview str, sview substr){
    return str.find(substr) != string::npos;
}

inline bool startsWith(sview str, sview prefix) {
    return str.size() >= prefix.size() && str.compare(0,  prefix.size(), prefix) == 0;
}

// just to hold the alphabet not really, could just use a vector. Was more for debug.
class Alphabet{
public:
    Alphabet() = default;
    Alphabet(const Alphabet&) = default;
    Alphabet(Alphabet&&) = default;
    Alphabet& operator=(const Alphabet&) = default;
    Alphabet& operator=(Alphabet&&) = default;
    Alphabet(const svector& sv) : m_letters(sv){}
    ~Alphabet() = default;

    ivector prefixLengths(sview str) const;
    const svector& letters() const { return m_letters; }
    void prepare(const string&);

private:
    svector m_letters;
};


// prepare alphabet by removing junk
void Alphabet::prepare(const string& str)
{

    //remove duplicate strings
    std::sort(m_letters.begin(), m_letters.end());
    m_letters.erase( std::unique( m_letters.begin(), m_letters.end() ), m_letters.end() );

    for(auto it = m_letters.begin() ; it != m_letters.end(); ) {
        if (it->empty())                    //remove empty strings
            it = m_letters.erase(it);
        else if(!isSubStringOf(str, *it))   //remove letters that don't appear in str
            it = m_letters.erase(it);
        else
            ++it;
    }
}


// return vector of the unique lengths of all letters that start the word str
ivector Alphabet::prefixLengths(sview str) const
{
    ivector result;
    for(auto prefix : m_letters)
        if(startsWith(str, prefix))
            result.push_back(prefix.size());

    return result;
}


// create a vector of string views by removing prefixes from given views
sviews nextViews(const sviews& views, const Alphabet& strings)
{
    sviews result;
    for(auto v : views){
        auto lengths = strings.prefixLengths(v);
        for(auto e : lengths){
            sview sv(v);
            sv.remove_prefix(e);
            result.push_back(sv);
        }
    }
    // ["a", "bc"] and ["ab", "c"] will both yield a prefix length of 3
    // so we will get the same view of the word so remove duplicates views
    std::sort(result.begin(), result.end());
    result.erase( std::unique( result.begin(), result.end() ), result.end() );

    return result;
}



int main(int, char**)
{
    const string word = "abcdabcdabcdbccbcabchk";
    const svector letters = { "ab", "abc", "c", "bc", "cd", "hk" };


    // tidy up the alphabet to only include letters that appear in the word
    // and remove empty letters and duplicates
    Alphabet alphabet(letters);
    alphabet.prepare(word);

    // we start with a view of the original word
    sviews views = { word };

    // keep stripping off prefixes from the views until we get an empty view
    // or we have no more to try
    while(!views.empty()){
        bool success = std::find_if(
            views.begin(),
            views.end(),
            [](auto e){ return e.empty(); })  != views.end();

        if(success){
            cout << "success\n";
            return 0;
        }
        views = nextViews(views, alphabet);
    }

    cout << "fail\n"; // we ran out of views to find prefixes for
    return 0;
}
```

================================================================

Update: Trimmed down version without the junk

We can throw away all the junk I used for debug and just keep a record of
the set of indices into the word.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <string_view>
#include <set>

using std::cout;
using std::string;
using svector = std::vector<string>;        // string vector
using ivector = std::vector<std::size_t>;   // index vector
using sview = std::string_view;             // string_view
using iset = std::set<std::size_t>;         // index set



inline bool isSubStringOf(sview str, sview substr){
    return str.find(substr) != string::npos;
}


inline bool startsWith(sview str, sview prefix) {
    return str.size() >= prefix.size() && str.compare(0, prefix.size(), prefix) == 0;
}


// prepare alphabet by removing junk
svector prepare(const svector& letters, const string& word)
{
    svector result = letters;

    //remove duplicate strings
    std::sort(result.begin(), result.end());
    result.erase( std::unique( result.begin(), result.end() ),   result.end() );

    for(auto it = result.begin() ; it != result.end(); ) {
        if (it->empty())                    //remove empty strings
            it = result.erase(it);
        else if(!isSubStringOf(word, *it))  //remove strings that don't appear in word
            it = result.erase(it);
        else
            ++it;
    }
    return result;
}


// vector of lengths of letters that prefix str
ivector prefixLengths(sview str, const svector& letters)
{
    ivector result;
    for(auto& prefix : letters)
        if(startsWith(str, prefix))
            result.push_back(prefix.size());

    return result;
}


// return view of string advanced by i chars
sview advanceViewOf(std::size_t i, const string& str)
{
    sview view(str);
    view.remove_prefix(i);
    return view;
}


// return set of indices into word for all prefixes
iset nextIndexSet(const iset& indices, const string& word, const svector& letters)
{
    iset result;
    for(std::size_t i : indices){
        for(std::size_t length : prefixLengths(advanceViewOf(i, word), letters))
            result.insert(i + length);
    }
    return result;
}


const string word = "abcdabcdabcdbccbcabchk";
const std::size_t wordLength = word.size();
const svector letters = { "a", "ab", "abc", "c", "bc", "cd", "hk" };


int main(int, char**)
{
    svector alphabet = prepare(letters, word);
    iset indices = {0};

    do{
        bool success = indices.find(wordLength) != indices.end();
        if(success){
            cout << "success\n";
            return 0;
        }
        indices = nextIndexSet(indices, word, letters);
    }while(!indices.empty());

    cout << "fail\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Will it give the correct result for: string: `abefgc`; substrings: `['efg', 'abc']`?

Comment: @bambo-otrit Yes. Although probably easier to try it than post here tbh.

Comment: `'abefgc'` isn't a concatenation of `'efg', 'abc'`

Comment: @bambo-otrit. Ah! Yes I see what you mean now. Good point!. Wonder if we can do anything about that. Good spot :)

Comment: We may try this approach: 1) Put all substrings into a hash table. Iterate through the string and search its substrings in the hash table. We start with a 1 character substring in the current position and increase its length by one. We Record positions of found substrings in a stack. By reaching the end of the string we may return `true` or go back to the previous index from the stack, remove it from the stack and try to find a larger substring in the hash table from that position.

Comment: @bambo-otrit Sounds like a plan. Got one of those wonderful zoom things shortly. Back this afternoon will give it a go. What else does one have to do in lockdown? :(

Comment: A small example: for `zzzabcdefg` and `['abc', 'abcd', 'efg', 'zzz']` we found `zzz`, `abc`, but failed to find `defg`. We go back to the position 3, and look for `abcd`, then `efg`

Comment: The new version looks promising.

Comment: @bartolo-otrit Yes it looks a bit more sensible. Have updated it to throw away all the junk I was using to debug. Now we just keep the set of indices into the word and create views into it on the fly. I think this is more like what you suggested in you earlier comments.